# How can I use a DLL written in C

Tags: c#, c, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm a newbie in *DLL management*.

It turns out that I need to use the GNU Libmicrohttpd library found at this [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/)

In this library, the problem I have found is that it is written in **C** and the project I am doing is in **.Net** and when I try to add the DLL in Visual studio it marks the following error:

[image: Error]

What possibility can I have to add it to the project? I appreciate your cooperation.

Comment: That approach is not going to work, you would need to use p/invoke - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/dotnet/calling-native-functions-from-managed-code - There are going to be significantly easier options using a different .Net HTTP server implementation such as httpListener.

Comment: You need to create your own interface for the C dll and provide entry point (export) for the functions you want PInvoke in C#. You can start here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/403285/P-Invoke-Tutorial-Basics-Part